# See Exactly Which Files Windows Access On Boot Up

Tags: windows-7, windows, monitoring, workstation

I am looking for a method to monitor exactly which files are being accessed on boot up by Windows. This is in attempts to find a bottle neck on physical workstations, but I would also like this information for all workstations in general. I can run the image in a VM, using a SAN as the disk location. I just need a fairly easy way to see which files are being touched on boot up.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for something like BootVis?

Comment: @ChrisN that certainly seems like what I am looking for. I will do some more reading at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default.aspx and http://www.raymond.cc/blog/winbootinfo-is-a-bootvis-alternative-that-works-in-windows-vista-and-7/ (This seems a little sketchy though)

Comment: The unfortunate thing is, that BootVis is XP only. And the link on raymond.cc is broken...

Comment: Windows Performance Recorder and Windows Performance Analyzer seem promising though.

Comment: Yeah, I think that might do what you want to do - I didn't look into it much, though. Something else you might want to consider is [Soluto](http://soluto.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a Boot trace, as shown [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jeff_stokes/archive/2012/09/17/how-to-collect-a-good-boot-trace-on-windows-7.aspx) or [here](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2011/07/windows-performance-toolkit-to-trace-the-windows-7-startup-performance/).

Alternatively you can use the Event Viewer, read [this tutorial](http://itexpertvoice.com/home/what%E2%80%99s-taking-so-long-how-to-fight-slow-startup-times-in-windows-7/) for more info.